# How to separate the output of a list in R

Tags: r

I have a function which return a list of list. I would like to separate the result of the list. The first elements from the second elements. 
Here is an example:

```
x1 <- replicate(4,0.5)
x2 <- replicate(4,0.7)
x <- list(x1,x2)
y <- list(0.5,0.6,0.3,0.4)
myfu <- function(x,y){
  out <- list()
out$y <- lapply(1:4, function(i){lapply(1:2, function(j) y[[i]]*x[[j]])})
return(out)
}
```

This function returns this:

```
    $y
$y[[1]]
$y[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25

$y[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0.35 0.35 0.35 0.35


$y[[2]]
$y[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3

$y[[2]][[2]]
[1] 0.42 0.42 0.42 0.42


$y[[3]]
$y[[3]][[1]]
[1] 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15

$y[[3]][[2]]
[1] 0.21 0.21 0.21 0.21


$y[[4]]
$y[[4]][[1]]
[1] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2

$y[[4]][[2]]
[1] 0.28 0.28 0.28 0.28
```

My question is, How can I separate all `y[[i]][[1]]` from all `y[[i]][[2]]`. That is, I would like to have a result like this:

```
$y
$y[[1]]
$y[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25

$y[[2]]
$y[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3

$y[[3]]
$y[[3]][[1]]
[1] 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15


$y[[4]]
$y[[4]][[1]]
[1] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
```

and the same for the second element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may in your way of implementing `lapply` function. The easiest way to get what you want is just slightly changing your `lapply` function. That is,

```
x1 <- replicate(4,0.5)
x2 <- replicate(4,0.7)
x <- list(x1,x2)
y <- list(0.5,0.6,0.3,0.4)
myfu <- function(x,y){
  out <- list()
  out$y <- lapply(1:2, function(i){lapply(1:4, function(j) y[[j]]*x[[i]])})

  return(out)
}
```

Hence, the output is:

```
> myfu(x,y)
$y
$y[[1]]
$y[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25

$y[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3

$y[[1]][[3]]
[1] 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15

$y[[1]][[4]]
[1] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2


$y[[2]]
$y[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.35 0.35 0.35 0.35

$y[[2]][[2]]
[1] 0.42 0.42 0.42 0.42

$y[[2]][[3]]
[1] 0.21 0.21 0.21 0.21

$y[[2]][[4]]
[1] 0.28 0.28 0.28 0.28
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `transpose`

```
library(purrr)
myfu(x, y) %>%
      map(transpose)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is really great. Can we used it inside the function?

Comment: @Alice Yes, you can do `out %>%
        map(transpose)` and then call `myfu(x, y)`

Comment: I think the problem is in the way how  implementing `lapply` function.